# Create .exe file from VS code using python with conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently running an interface using the VS code. I have located the file where .py saved. I run terminal using the following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile AI_VS_TEST.py
```

the created dist file is empty.

The error I can see in the terminal line as follow:

```
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using a version of Python older than 3.6 when [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag) was added to `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

as stated here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4199#issuecomment-487303420

For me doing this solved the problem:

```
pip uninstall -y enum34
```